No way to notify a user when they are added as a case team member?
I am blown away that this seemingly simple functionality is missing - There is no simple way in setup to send an email to a member after you add them to a case team. I was resigned to doing a more complicated route (a flow or a trigger that fires off an email on create of a CaseTeamMember record) but that object isnt even an option to select in either a flow or trigger! It looks like you can create flows/triggers on campaign member and opportunity team member so I'm not sure what the reason is here.
I know I can query the CaseTeamMembers table in Apex but I have no way of automating this to send the email on create... does anyone have any suggestions?

It's simply not triggerable. Generally, the canonical approach is to write a scheduled job (likely a batch) that you run on an interval. Each execution, you look for records created since the last run. Then you run logic against those records.

Interesting, I have plenty of experience writing scheduled batches but can you elaborate on how you capture the last job run time in a way that can be retrieved/referenced in my Apex class?

@Chris That's just a Custom Setting you'd create.
